# How can I remove the sometimes huge white space at the bottom of an \fbox automatically?

Tags: equations, boxes, white-space

This is the code:

```
\subsection{Definition: Signale, Symbole}
        \fbox{%
            \parbox{\textwidth}{%
                \textit{Signale} sind zeitabhängige und messbare physikalische Größen. Definierten messbaren Signaländerungen lässt sich ein \textit{Symbol} zuordnen. Diese Symbole repräsentieren Information.
            }%
        }
        \subsection{Definition: Information}
        \fbox{%
            \parbox{\textwidth}{%
                \textit{Information} besteht in der \textit{Unsicherheit}, Veränderungen eines Signals vorhersagen zu können. Der Informationsgehalt eines Zeichens $x \in \mathcal{X}$ hängt von einer Wahrscheinlichkeit $p(x)$ ab, dass das informationstragende Signal zum Beobachtungszeitpunkt den diesem Zeichen zugeordneten Wert beziehungsweise Wertebereich annimmt. Der Informationsgehalt $I$ des Zeichens $x$ mit der Auftrittswahrscheinlichkeit $p(x)$ ist definiert als
                \begin{equation}
                I(x) = -\log_2 p(x) \ \mathrm{mit} \ [I] = \mathrm{ bit}
                \end{equation}
            }%
        }
```

And this is the result with annoying white space at the bottom marked in red:

[image]

How can I get rid of it?

Putting `\\[-1.2 cm]` after `\end{equation}` would do the job, but isn’t there are better solution which avoids these sometimes huge white spaces in general?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\removevspace{%
\par\unskip\unskip\unpenalty
\showthe\lastnodetype
}
\begin{document}

\subsection{Definition: Signale, Symbole}
        \fbox{%
            \parbox{\textwidth}{%THIS IS OVER-FULL
                \textit{Signale} sind zeitabhängige und messbare physikalische Größen. Definierten messbaren Signaländerungen lässt sich ein \textit{Symbol} zuordnen. Diese Symbole repräsentieren Information.
            \removevspace}%
        }
        \subsection{Definition: Information}
        \fbox{%
            \parbox{\textwidth}{%THIS IS OVER-FULL
                \textit{Information} besteht in der \textit{Unsicherheit}, Veränderungen eines Signals vorhersagen zu können. Der Informationsgehalt eines Zeichens $x \in \mathcal{X}$ hängt von einer Wahrscheinlichkeit $p(x)$ ab, dass das informationstragende Signal zum Beobachtungszeitpunkt den diesem Zeichen zugeordneten Wert beziehungsweise Wertebereich annimmt. Der Informationsgehalt $I$ des Zeichens $x$ mit der Auftrittswahrscheinlichkeit $p(x)$ ist definiert als
                \begin{equation}
                I(x) = -\log_2 p(x) \ \mathrm{mit} \ [I] = \mathrm{ bit}
                \end{equation}
            \removevspace}%
        }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with the `framed` package, which can break across pages. Just redefine `\belowdisplayskip` to 0pt before the equation:

```
\documentclass[german]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength\FrameSep{5pt}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\subsection{Definition: Signale, Symbole}
\begin{framed}\noindent
  \textit{Signale} sind zeitabhängige und messbare physikalische Größen. Definierten messbaren Signaländerungen lässt sich ein \textit{Symbol} zuordnen. Diese Symbole repräsentieren Information.
\end{framed}

\subsection{Definition: Information}
\begin{framed}\noindent
  \textit{Information} besteht in der \textit{Unsicherheit}, Veränderungen eines Signals vorhersagen zu können. Der Informationsgehalt eines Zeichens $x ∈ \mathcal{X}$ hängt von einer Wahrscheinlichkeit $p(x)$ ab, dass das informationstragende Signal zum Beobachtungszeitpunkt den diesem Zeichen zugeordneten Wert beziehungsweise Wertebereich annimmt. Der Informationsgehalt $I$ des Zeichens $x$ mit der Auftrittswahrscheinlichkeit $p(x)$ ist definiert als \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
  \begin{equation}
    I(x) = -\log₂ p(x) \ \mathrm{mit} \ [I] = \mathrm{ bit}
  \end{equation}
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

[image]